# Accounts tab broken in network profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, network-profile

As of today, this is what I see on [my accounts page](https://stackexchange.com/users/178805/ilmari-karonen?tab=accounts):

[image: Screenshot]

I'm pretty sure I used to have accounts on more SE sites than only Area 51...

Comment: It's what I see for [my account](http://stackexchange.com/users/79630/kiamlaluno?tab=accounts) too.

Comment: Even [Jeff Atwood](http://stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=accounts) is affected :) (Mine seems fine.)

Comment: [Relevant comment crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131484/list-of-accounts-only-contains-one-account#comment362581_131484)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We found your accounts! They should now appear appropriately.

We added a new "site state" yesterday and figured a few places would crop up that we didn't *account* for...this one's solved, your accounts should appear within the next few minutes are the cache expires.  If you notice any other cross-site weirdness, please do report it here on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like it's indeed working again now.

Comment: [Yes!! I was right!!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131484/list-of-accounts-only-contains-one-account#comment362581_131484).